# Sub rotinas no vb6

Tags: visual-basic-6

Tenho um formulário e adicionei a ele , um botão e uma imagem ,quero saber se e  possível criar uma sub rotina onde ao clicar no botão a imagem mova se  de um lado para o outro?se for possível  como fica no . vb6 Desde já a gradeço a ajuda de vocês abraços

Comment: Em vez de deletar suas perguntas, melhore-as seguindo as dicas dadas nos comentários. Depois que a pessoa atualiza e melhora o post, podemos reverter o voto negativo que foi dado.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer isso criando um `Timer` em seu `Form`, como mostrado na figura abaixo:

[image: Timer no Form]

Em seguida, basta ajustar as propriedades `Interval` e `Enabled` do `Timer` criado, para poder criar um evento repetitivo (onde você fará seu `PictureBox` se mover), como nesse código:

```
Option Explicit

Private Indo As Boolean

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Inicialmente, desliga o timer, e configura seu intervalo
    '(quanto menor, mais rápido)
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Interval = 10
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    '10 é um valor arbitrário (quanto maior, mais vai se mover)
    If Indo = True Then
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left + 10
        'Se bateu no lado direito, volta
        If Picture1.Left >= ScaleWidth - Picture1.Width Then
            Indo = False
            Picture1.Left = ScaleWidth - Picture1.Width
        End If
    Else
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left - 10
        'Se bateu no lado esquero, vai de novo
        If Picture1.Left <= 0 Then
            Indo = True
            Picture1.Left = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Sem utilizar `Timer`, conforme pedido (não é a melhor prática):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Do While True
        If Indo = True Then
            Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left + 10
            'Se bateu no lado direito, volta
           If Picture1.Left >= ScaleWidth - Picture1.Width Then
                Indo = False
                Picture1.Left = ScaleWidth - Picture1.Width
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left - 10
            'Se bateu no lado esquero, vai de novo
           If Picture1.Left <= 0 Then
                Indo = True
                Picture1.Left = 0
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Com 4 botões, um para cada direção, conforme pedido:

```
Option Explicit

Private dir As Long

Private Sub cmdUp_Click()
    dir = 0
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdLeft_Click()
    dir = 1
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDown_Click()
    dir = 2
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRight_Click()
    dir = 3
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Select Case dir
    Case 0
        Picture1.Top = Picture1.Top - 10
    Case 1
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left - 10
    Case 2
        Picture1.Top = Picture1.Top + 10
    Case 3
        Picture1.Left = Picture1.Left + 10
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: é possível fazer isto sem o timer usando  um ciclo?

Comment: Oi @user7752. Você pode fazer isso sem o `Timer`. Basta utilizar um `While`, `For`, ou qualquer outra estrutura de laço que desejar, colocando ao final do laço o comando `DoEvents`, para não "travar" a janela. Mas essa solução não é muito aconselhável ;)

Comment: Tentei com o comando DoEventes dei o primeiro click move apenas uma vez ,  não move se  ate que eu de um outro click no botao e eu queria que ao dar um click ele mova se sobre o form, não tem uma outra maneira eficaz de fazer isto?

Comment: Oi @user7752. Fiz uma versão (adicionada na resposta). Mas, honestamente, fica tão, tão rápido que você não verá a animação. Realmente é só para você matar sua curiosidade, porque é uma péssima técnica em aplicações no dia-a-dia ;)

Comment: A imagem so move apenas para um unico lado e o processo é  muito rapido Não tem como ser um pouco mais lento como faz um leitor de musica  vlc por exemplo quando estiver a tocar de como se movimenta é como gostaraa que fiicase.

Comment: Onde posso encontrar bons manuais de vb6?

Comment: Oi @user7752... Então, é rápido, mesmo! Para ficar mais devagar, teria que fazer a `Thread` dormir, o que iria arruinar com a resposta da UI (janela). Por isso disse que era uma má prática, e tinha que usar o `Timer` ;) Agora manuais... não sei, não :(

Comment: Amigao não tem como fazer a imagem dar a volta sobre o formulário sem parar (assim como está agora, sem o timer)? Já tentei mas não deu certo não.

Comment: @user7752 ... então, sem o `Timer`, no VB6 não dá. Existem outras técnicas, mas são mais complicadas que o `Timer` do VB6.

Comment: Não tens algum código ou algo relacionado  um  ciclo usando um FOR ou um outro laco de decisão capaz de fazer istosem o timer?

Comment: @user7752 Então, não é uma questão do tipo de laço. `Do`, `While`, `For` são semelhantes. A questão é mais profunda do que isso. É um problema de `Thread` e processamento. Ou faz com um `Timer`, ou faz criando outra `Thread` (direta ou indiretamente). De qualquer outro jeito vai destruir com a resposta do seu programa.

Comment: desculpe Carlos e com o timer como ficaria?

Comment: @user7752 Fica como no primeiro código que postei na resposta ;)

Comment: Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()
Do Until Me.Width < 4000
Let Image1.Left = Image1.Left - 5
DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
Assim como esta permite mover a imagem do lado direito para esquerdo como fazer para a imagem rodar todo o fomulário,Sem parar com um botão e sem usar o timer? Alguem tem uma ideia eficaz de como fazer isso?

Comment: @user7752 ... Desculpe, além das três formas da resposta, sem utilizar outros componentes externos, não sei outra forma de fazer. Só lembrando, travar em um `loop/while/for` com um `DoEvents` ao final funciona, mas não é a melhor opção para uma aplicação real. Existe algum motivo para não querer utilizar um `Timer`?